# Is there anything like a RoboTask for Linux?

Tags: linux, automation

For those who don't know about Robotask you could find info [here](http://www.robotask.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of. Most automation in Linux based systems is done with [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). If you wan't conditional task scheduling like they advertise, you can get cron to run a script (shell, Perl, Python, whatever you like) to check for the certain conditions and run programs accordingly. As for things like automated e-mail checking, this can be achieved with cron and the Firefox add-on [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863).

For simulating mouse and keypress events in other locations you can use [XMacro](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/). Of course this can also be used with cron by itself or in shell scripts.

Comment: Can I achieve something like simulating mouse clicks at specific locations and also keypress events.

Comment: Yep, check out XMacro: http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/ It can record events and play them back. Simply schedule cron to run your recorded event.

Comment: @kevin boyd: `expect` can also do this if you don't need the mouse simulation.